# Using SVM on top of CNN extracted features - How to do Multi-Class classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, multiclass-classification

In MNIST data set, there's 10 classification output. Now, I like to using **SVM** as a classifier for this classification task. I used CNN architecture ( excluding top layer or classifier ) to extract a feature from the raw image first and then fit it in SVM classifier.

SVM is a binary classifier, so we can use **One-vs-One** or **One-vs-Rest** approach to doing such things. I use below implemented code from sci-kit learn official doc. But couldn't realize where I specify to model about the multi-class label or this is **One-One** or **One-Rest** approach.

The data set shape looks below:

```
train : (2045, 32, 32)
label : (2045, 10)
```

After extracting feature using non-top CNN code, we get:

```
train : (7636, 256)  < - cnn_Xtrain
label : (7636,)      < - Ytrain
```

The SVM classifier I've tried

```
# SVC classifier
SVMC = SVC(probability=True)
svc_param_grid = {'kernel': ['rbf'], 
                  'gamma': [0.0001, 0.001],
                  'C': [1, 10, 50]}

gsSVMC = GridSearchCV(SVMC, param_grid = svc_param_grid, cv = K_fold,
                      scoring="accuracy", n_jobs= -1, verbose = 1)

gsSVMC.fit(cnn_Xtrain, Ytrain) # fitting extracted features

SVMC_best = gsSVMC.best_estimator_
```

In this classifier how SVM understand this is a multi-class problem or one-vs-one or one-vs-rest? The scoring result is more suspicious to me, I evaluate almost 98% indeed. Is kernel specified in grid-search ( RBF ) responsible for this? Or I just did something wrong here?

In addition, is it fine to extract the feature from the raw image using CNN codes and then fit it in SVM or similar classifier?

Comment: SVM will handle multiclass automatically if your training dataset contains more than two classes. If you check the popular Iris classification [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html) which has 3 classes. It will be a good idea to use a confusion matrix to check for MNIST data set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decision weather to use one-vs-rest or one-vs-one is set in the 'decision_function_shape' parameter of the classifier (see [doc for svc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC)). There it states:

> Whether to return a one-vs-rest (‘ovr’) decision function of shape (n_samples, n_classes) as all other classifiers, or the original one-vs-one (‘ovo’) decision function of libsvm which has shape (n_samples, n_classes * (n_classes - 1) / 2). However, one-vs-one (‘ovo’) is always used as multi-class strategy.
>   Changed in version 0.19: decision_function_shape is ‘ovr’ by default.
>   New in version 0.17: decision_function_shape=’ovr’ is recommended.
>   Changed in version 0.17: Deprecated decision_function_shape=’ovo’ and None.

so now one vs rest is the default and since you didn't specify this parameter it is probably what was used in your code.

As for your question about using CNN for feature extraction before fitting: In general it should work. However, using the right kernel it should not really be necessary. If you want to do reduce the dimension of your feature vectors, you can just use [pca](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) or non linear embedding methods like [manifold embedding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/manifold.html) to get less features.

hope this helps.

Comment: So, One-vs-Rest is by default in SVM. Is it for all other this type of binary classifier or we should check manually? And why you're saying using the right Kernel, extracting feature using CNN is not really necessary? If I want to reduce the dimension of features vector, which approach is more convenient between CNN extractor or PCA like something?

Comment: @DavidLe when in doubt I would always check the documentation which approach is implemented for the specific classifier. The raw features should be fine for classification since kernels allow for curvature in the hyper-plane separating the data, therefor the features extracted by a CNN don't really help much (usually in my personal opinion!! test it if you want to know for sure...). In terms of convenience, PCA is very fast and easy, it can't hurt to see if it is already good enough.